# Apache2 Ubuntu: sudo a2ensite

Tags: laravel, apache2

I'm new to VPS, I've set up an Apache2 on a ubuntu-focal-20-x86_64 and trying to host a site based on Laravel.

Everything seems to be set, but when accessing the IP I get an error.

I created a new Virtual host, followed these commands:

```
sudo mv example /var/www/html/
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/html/example/
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/example/storage
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo nano example.conf
```

I also restarted the server.

Virtual host, [IP] = my servers ip without HTTP:// Example: 127.0.0.1

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName [IP]
   ServerAdmin webmaster@[IP]
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/public

   <Directory /var/www/html/example>
       AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When not using the Virtual host I connect to the Apache landingpage, PHP works.

What am I missing?

EDIT:
I checked the error.log from above and found this

```
[Thu Sep *** 2020] [php7:warn] [pid ***] [client [IP]] PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/example/public/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/example/public/index.php on line 34
[Thu Sep 17 09:25:44.*** 2020] [php7:error] [pid ***] [client [IP]] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/example/public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/example/public/index.php on line 34
```

EDIT: Seems to be a problem with my Laravel project

Comment: Have you already run composer install? Is there a vendor folder in your project? Is /vendor/autoload.php present?

Comment: Yes. I deleted the project and created a new one, it run snoothly after that. Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be my Laravel project that needed a new installation.

Comment: Nice, you answered your own question. I am curious, did you answer it right when you posted the question (Q&A Type), or did you find the answer later?

Comment: Thank you. I continued the troubleshooting after I posted the question, added info along the way and luckily I managed to find the problem through the error log. I'd been struggeling a couple of hours before I asked for help.